# What are some ways to implement the Money Class in Java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, currency

I you can use the BigDecimal class since it provides operations for arithmetic, scale manipulation, rounding, comparison, hashing, and format conversion.

I was just wondering what were some other ways to implement it?

Comment: FYI: Java 9 will have a Money/Currency API included within the JDK. However, it'll be another 3 years (at least !) until that comes out...

Answer (score 1):

money calculations are best done in integers, counting cents.

so your options are as follows:

1. if youre 100% sure you will never need to represent a number larger than `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` cents, go with long.
2. if you need anything larger, go with BigInteger.

**EDIT** - as @arshajii pointed out in the comments, for some application areas (mostly stock market / futures) you count cent fractions, 5+ digits after the decimal point. if thats your intended application there's an even bigger chance that you'll have to use BigInteger.

Comment: Counting cents is not always good enough. For example, currency conversions can result in fractions of cents, and this must often be kept track of.

Comment: @arshajii - in real life it very much depends on the application. for most stock/futures applications you use 5 decimal digits, maybe more. for retail code (shopping) and personal money-tracking you tend to round to whole cents.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use classes from the [Joda Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) project. It's developped by Stephen Colebourne, of Joda Time fame.

It provides useful classes to represent amounts of money, parse and format them from/to a String, and many other related utility methods.

Answer (score 0):

int? just make sure you never use floats or double for cents etc due to floating point rounding issues.

```
//$100.52
int value = 10052;

int wholeDollars = value/100;
int cents = value %100;
```

Comment: int is a bit tight here. 4 billion cents are ~40 million dollars, which any serious money-related program is likely to encounter, and then overflow. on 64-bit hardware (which is pretty much anything these days) ints and longs actually cost you the same, and you get more breathing room with longs